# How to convert NA from factor vector to value of 0

Tags: r, na

I want to convert NA from factor vector to value of 0

This is an example

```
myVec <- c(NA, 1, 2, NA)
myVec
[1] NA  1  2 NA

myVec <- factor(myVec)
[1] <NA> 1    2    <NA>
Levels: 1 2

for(i in 1:4){  
if(  is.na(myVec[i])  ) { myVec[i] = "0"}
}

Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `0` to the possible factor values

```
levels(myVec) <- 0:2
```

and substitute NA values by 0

```
myVec[is.na(myVec)] <- 0
myVec
# [1] 0 0 1 0
# Levels: 0 1 2
```

Or, beforehand when the factor is created...

```
(myvec <- factor(ifelse(is.na(myVec), 0, myVec)))
# [1] 0 1 2 0
# Levels: 0 1 2
```

Comment: The last function actually worked. The first function change the the values of myVec to [1] 0 0 1 0  it should be [1] 0 1 2 0

Comment: Alternatively, using my favourite `replace` function: `factor(replace(myVec,is.na(myVec),0))`

Answer (score 1):

One way might be to create a logical vector which contains whether the particular vector entry is na or not and then assigns the value 0 to each matching entry. E.g

```
navector <- is.na (myVec)
myVec [navector] <- 0
```

Actually above can be done in one line even

```
myVec [ is.na (myVec) ] <- 0
```

Comment: Yea, Luke answer was better. You need to add factor levels. My bad; see Lukes answer.